# hiding html buttons from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0

hiding html buttons from code behind

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="delete" runat="server" class="bt1" onserverclick="button2" />
```

Code behind

```
Button mybut1 = (Button)FindControl("Button1");
                    mybut1.Visible = false;
```

Another One

```
Button2.visible=false
```

Both are not working

Comment: You cant access html buttons from code behind, Replace it with asp.net buttons

Comment: @Hemal we can access any html control from code behind, if it has *ID* and *runat="server"* attributes

Answer (score 4):

Your html:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="delete" runat="server" class="bt1" onserverclick="button2" />
```

You can use

```
Button1.Visible = false;
```

Or

```
Button1.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");
```

Both works.

Hope it helps you.